# Assembly: allocate registers into array from C

Tags: arrays, c, assembly, mips

I have a code in C and I need to translate it into assembly in a dinamic way.
Is there a simple way I could do that?

The C code:

```
int size, i;
    
    printf("Type array size:");
    scanf("%d", &size);
     
    int vector[size]; 
    for (i = 0; i<size; i++){
        printf("type value of array[%d]: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &vector[i]);
    }
```

My Mips code:
So far, I haven't been translating it dinamically, it just prints the same prompt over and over.

I need the prompt in assembly to look like the one in C.

```
.data
vec:    .space 0 
size: .asciiz "\n\n Type array size:"
prompt: .asciiz "Type value of array:"

.text
.globl main
main:

    la $a1, vec
    
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, size
    syscall

    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    move $a2, $v0 #$a2 holds array size
    
    j Loop

    Loop:
    beq $a2, $t1, END

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt 
    syscall

    li $v0,5 #gets value as printf 
    syscall
    move $s1,$v0
    
    sw $s1, 0($a1) 
    la $a1, 4($a1) #moves on to next value of the array
    addi $t1, $t1, 1
    j Loop

    END:
```

Comment: This is certainly not intel, looks more like mips. Anyway, if your array is static just allocate 4 words in your data section and store the items there.

Answer (score -1):

a counter needed to be used and its value needed to be updated inside the loop

```
.data
vec:    .space 0 
size: .asciiz "\n\n Type array size:"
prompt: .asciiz "Type value of array:["
closebrack: .asciiz "]"


.text

.globl main

main:
    la $a1, vec
    li $t0, 0 #counter=0
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, size
    syscall
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    move $a2, $v0 #$a2 holds array size  
    j Loop


    Loop:
    beq $a2, $t1, END
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt 
    syscall
    add, $t0, 1 #counter++
    move $a0, $t0     
    li $v0, 1        #print counter
    syscall
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, closebrack # print the closing bracket "]"
    syscall
    li $v0,5 #gets value as printf 
    syscall
    move $s1,$v0 
    sw $s1, 0($a1) 
    la $a1, 4($a1) #moves on to next value of the array
    addi $t1, $t1, 1
    j Loop

    END:
    li, $v0,10
    syscall
```

Comment: Welcome to the site.  You can [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) code using code blocks.

Comment: `vec: .space 0` reserves no bytes.  If you want to match the C semantics, you need to reserve a variable amount of space on the stack.